# Can each SyncChunk be synchronized individually during a full sync client's sync session?

Tags: synchronization, evernote

The Evernote EDAM sync specification at https://dev.evernote.com/media/pdf/edam-sync.pdf is a little confusing with regard to the processing of sync chunks.

It seems to indicate that all sync chunks should be downloaded via calls to `GetSyncChunk` before any are processed.

However this seems inefficient in memory, particularly on mobile.

It is OK to process each sync chunk one at a time instead? Is each sync chunk self-consistent in its content (that is, there are no referenced entities like notebooks or resources whose metadata is not in the sync chunk)?

Comment: I don't have an authoritative answer to your actual question, but it is possible to serialize sync chunks to temp storage on disk during your fetching phase, and then when you have got them all, process them off of local disk.